# Computer Science Circles?

Tags: python, python-3.x, computer-science

Here are two problems which I do not know what I am coding wrong:

1. In physics, for a pendulum with length L and initial angle A, its horizontal displacement X(T) at time T is given by the formula

   X(T) = L × cos(A × cos(T × √9.8/L)) - L × cos(A)

   Write a program which takes two lines of input; the first line is L and the second line is A. The output should be ten lines, giving the values of X(0), X(1), X(2), ..., X(9). For example, if the first line of input is 53.1 and the second line of input is 0.8, then the first line of output is 0.0 and the second line of output is 53.1*cos(0.8*cos(1*√9.8/53.1)) - 53.1*cos(0.8) ~ 2.6689.

   Here is what I have, although the grader shows that I am doing some of the math wrong:

   ```
   import math
   L = float(input())
   A = float(input())
   for i in range (0, 10):
      x = L * math.cos(A * math.cos(i * math.sqrt(9.8/L))-L * math.cos(A))
      print(x)
   ```
2. For this program, the first line of input is an integer width. Then, there are some lines of text; the line "END" indicates the end of the text. For each line of text, you need to print out a centered version of it, by adding periods .. to the left and right, so that the total length of each line of text is width. (All input lines will have length at most width.) Centering means that the number of periods added to the left and added to the right should be equal if possible; if needed we allow one more period on the left than the right. For example, for input

   Here is what I have, although it isn't correct either:

   ```
   width = int(input())
   hi=input()
   while hi != "END":
      WordInput=input()
      x=len(WordInput)
      y=width-x
      half=y%2
      if half == 0:
         a = int(y/2)
         print("." * a)
      elif half == 1:
         b = int(y/2) + 1
         c = int(y/2)
         print("." * b,WordInput,"." * c)
   ```

Comment: For 1, the last bracket should not be here following your formula. For 2 you should show the expected output and the current one.

Answer (score 0):

It may help you debug if your inputs have text prompts, as in `width = int(input("enter width: "))`, which will give you a better idea of where in the code your input will be stored.

I'm not seeing the problem with #1, but it's been a while since I've taken physics. If your grader says just the math is wrong, double check the equation you're using, and add appropriate parentheses in the code to make sure the correct order of operations is done.

There are several problems with #2. First, your program requests input the wrong number of times. Your loop depends on the variable `hi`, which you only assign once; once your code enters the loop, nothing will change it to "END" and the loop will never exit. Not only that, but the first word you enter (at the `hi` prompt) is not considered by code in your loop, so anything other than "END" is simply ignored. You'll want something more like this :

```
   WordInput=input()
   while WordInput != "END":
        # Do your processing and printing code here
        (...)
        # Then get some new input at the end of the loop            
        WordInput=input()
```

The new value of `WordInput` will be evaluated when the loop restarts.

Second, look at your `if` statement. You correctly determine that the length is even (half==0), but in the even case you don't tell the code to actually print the input word, just the periods! In practice, it's good to avoid setting up if/else blocks like this with multiple similar print statements; if you want to go back and change the formatting of one, you have to remember to manually change the others too. As your code gets more complicated this will become a real pain, so it's generally best to condense your print statements as much as you can. Without changing your structure too much here's how I would do it:

```
    if half == 0:
        a = int(y/2)
    elif half == 1:
        a = int(y/2) + 1
    b = int(y/2)
    print("." * a,WordInput,"." * b)
```

This way, `b` is assigned in either case and the same print statement will execute no matter what.

Third, any word that is printed and centered by your code is padded by spaces. This is because when you give `print()` multiple parameters, by default they are joined by spaces. To override this, you can change the separator parameter to an empty string (or anything else you need);

```
>>>print("." * 4, "Hey", "." * 4)
.... Hey ....

>>>print("." * 4, "Hey", "." * 4, sep="")
....Hey....
```

Answer (score 0):

For 1. The parentheses are wrong!

```
import math
L = float(input())
A = float(input())
for i in range (0, 10):
  x = L * math.cos(A * math.cos(i * math.sqrt(9.8/L)))-L * math.cos(A)
  print(x)
```